# Can't access k8s cluster in Linode LKE

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod, linode

I am trying to connect the LKE cluster on Linode with my terminal. Steps I've taken:

- created the cluster in Linode
- downloaded the generated cluster's .config file
- set KUBECONFIG context from the .config file

I can see that I'm **connected** to the cluster from the terminal:

```
$ kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME           CLUSTER    AUTHINFO         NAMESPACE
*         lke67746-ctx   lke67746   lke67746-admin   default
```

I can see the running pods through the Linode's web portal:

[image: running pods]

But when I try to list the pods through the terminal - I see **no pods**

```
$ kubectl get pods
No resources found in default namespace.
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: There are no pods in default namespace in fresh kubernetes cluster, run `kubectl get pods -A`  to see all pods in cluster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see no pods because your command only check on the `default` namespace.

To check the other pods, It's either you already know `your_namespace`, and you can `kubectl get pods -n your_namespace` or you can check all pods by this command:

```
kubectl get pods -A
```

If you want to get an idea about your namespaces `kubectl get namespaces`